# Bootstrap 4. Расположение navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Необходимо сделать навигационное меню как на картинке. Строго в центре экрана первый список меню, справа - другой. При сворачивании навигации в гамбургер правое меню должно центрироваться.

Реализовать я это смог прикрепив ко второму `navbar` класс `position-absolute` и стиль `right: 0`, думаю, что это костыль, а в верстке я не силен. Но при раскрытии гамбургера на маленьких экранах правый список не центрируется, что логично. Помогите реализовать такую навигацию, уже сил нет. В гугле почему-то именно такого варианта расположения меню не нашел.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код навигации:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">

<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main" aria-controls="navbar-main" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-main">

    <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="http://nazchurch/home">ГЛАВНАЯ</a>
            </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/about">О НАС</a>
            </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="http://nazchurch/news">НОВОСТИ</a>
            </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/preview">АНОНСЫ</a>
            </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/media">МЕДИА</a>
            </li>
                </ul>

    <ul class="navbar-nav position-absolute" style="right: 0">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="login-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Войти
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="login-dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://nazchurch/login">Один</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://nazchurch/register">Два</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Регистрация</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>

</nav>
```

Полный код:

https://jsfiddle.net/766vzm6q/2/

Answer (score 0):

Так как накартинке или нет?
https://jsfiddle.net/766vzm6q/4/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>News</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arsenal|Cormorant|Cormorant+Infant:300,400,500|Forum|Marck+Script" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/E31689DC-CDF7-9C4F-B0B5-DD43AB09E8E2/main.js" charset="UTF-8"></script></head>
<body>

    <div id="app" class="container">

        <div class="row mt-3">
            <div class="col text-center">
                <p style="font-family: 'Cormorant Infant', serif; margin-bottom: 4px">Превью</p>
                <h1 style="font-family: 'Marck Script', cursive; font-size: 60px; margin: 0 auto">Большой заголовок</h1>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main" aria-controls="navbar-main" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-main">

        <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="http://nazchurch/home">ГЛАВНАЯ</a>
                </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/about">О НАС</a>
                </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="http://nazchurch/news">НОВОСТИ</a>
                </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/preview">АНОНСЫ</a>
                </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/media">МЕДИА</a>
                </li>
                    </ul>

        <ul class="navbar-nav" style="">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="login-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Войти
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="login-dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://nazchurch/login">Один</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://nazchurch/register">Два</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Регистрация</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>

</nav>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row justify-content-end">
            <div class="col-12">
                            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
                    </div>

    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-slN8GvtUJGnv6ca26v8EzVaR9DC58QEwsIk9q1QXdCU8Yu8ck/tL/5szYlBbqmS+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: нет, первое меню должно быть строго по центру экрана

Comment: @rugleb так, а где оно находиться, если не по средине?

Comment: Так я и говорю по центру экрана (середине если хотите), но в вашем примере это не так. Я полную картинку приложил того как должно быть

Answer (score 0):

для мобильной версии удали position absolute у класса .position-absolute можете переоределить css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 764px){
    .position-absolute{
    position:relative;
    }
    }
```

или на js  просто удалить класс, как вам удобнее.
 я бы переопределил css..

Comment: Это выход, но больше похоже на костыль. А есть еще какие-нибудь варианты?

Comment: Я вам открою тайну, css состоит из костылей)
 а вообще я только что попробовал просто не добавлять класс position-absolute и либоя пьян либо это сработало
https://jsfiddle.net/766vzm6q/6/

Comment: скорее первое)
Первый список теперь не в центре экрана

Comment: тогда прошу прощения я реально накатил)

Comment: @rugleb Да, это абсолютно нормально - переопределить класс. В мобильной верстке без костылей не обойтись :)